# Feed list of column names to list then calculate by specific column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a wide dataset with specific columns I would like to multiply by another column with population weight, and replace the values once complete. When I run below (example) code, I get error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'list'.

Please advise on how I can make this work, **using the list**. Thanks!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['WGT']=0.5
cols_to_calc=['A', 'C']
df.update(df.columns.isin.list(cols_to_calc)).mul(df['WGT'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
df[cols_to_calc] = df[cols_to_calc].mul(df['WGT'], axis=0)
```